# How to set OnClickListener to get position of different ArrayLists using same Adapter java class?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, onclicklistener, android-viewholder

I am making an Android app, and currently have 3 different activities. One that displays '**Recent**' images from Flickr in a Recyclerview, another that displays '**Interesting**' images from Flickr in a Recyclerview, as well as a '**Details**' activity which displays a larger image view and more information about a particular photo when it is clicked.

I have two ArrayLists: **recentImageList** and **interestingImageList**, which use the same Adapter class to display the different images and their attributes (title, owner etc.) in their Recyclerviews, depending on the activity.

I have these two activities working and showing the correct content, and when I click on a 'recent' photo, it displays the same 'recent' photo on the 'details' page.

**However** my problem is that when an 'interesting' image is clicked, it passes the position of the 'recent' image to the Intent instead of the position of the 'interesting' image I clicked on. Therefore this displays the 'recent' image in the 'Details' activity, and not the 'interesting' photo I clicked on.

I am unsure how to pass the correct position of the interestingImageList array item in my onClickListener, so that the correct corresponding image is shown in my 'details' activity. Do I need some sort of if statement in my OnClickListener to determine which arraylist position is passed to the intent?

I'd be grateful for any help you guys can give. See the code for my ImageListAdapter class below:

```
public class ImageListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    ArrayList<ImageInfo> recentImageList;
    ArrayList<ImageInfo> interestingImageList;

    private int whichActivity;

    public ImageListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ImageInfo> recentImageList,
            ArrayList<ImageInfo> interestingImageList, int whichView) {
        this.context = context;
        this.recentImageList = recentImageList;
        this.interestingImageList = interestingImageList;
        whichActivity = whichView;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.cell_image_card, parent, false);
        return new ImageViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        if (whichActivity == 0) {
            ((ImageViewHolder) viewHolder).populate(recentImageList.get(position));
            ImageInfo recentInfo = recentImageList.get(position);
        } else if (whichActivity == 1) {
            ((ImageViewHolder) viewHolder).populate(interestingImageList.get(position - recentImageList.size()));
            ImageInfo interestingInfo = interestingImageList.get(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return recentImageList.size() + interestingImageList.size();
    }

    public class ImageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView imageTitle, ownerTitle, tags;
        public NetworkImageView mainImage, ownerImage;

        public ImageViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            imageTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageTitle);
            ownerTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ownerTitle);
            mainImage = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.mainImage);
            mainImage.setOnClickListener(onClick);
            ownerImage = (CircularNetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ownerImage);
        }

        public void populate(ImageInfo imageInfo) {
            ownerTitle.setText(imageInfo.owner);
            imageTitle.setText(imageInfo.title);
            mainImage.setImageUrl(imageInfo.url_m, NetworkMgr.getInstance(context).imageLoader);
            ownerImage.setImageUrl(imageInfo.ownerPic, NetworkMgr.getInstance(context).imageLoader);
        }

        View.OnClickListener onClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, DetailsActivity.class);
                int position = ImageViewHolder.this.getLayoutPosition();
                intent.putExtra("PHOTO_POSITION", position);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need two different instances of your adapter, each one for each list this seems like a wrong implementation

Each recyclerview should have its own adapter instance.
e.g.

```
new 
ImageListAdapter(this, recentImageList, null, whichView);
```

and

```
new 
    ImageListAdapter(this, null , interestingImageList,whichView);
```

Comment: Thanks, I have now made two instances of the adapter as above, however this has flagged up an error in my getItemCount() - 'attempting to involve virtual method int.java.util.ArrayList.size()' on a null object reference'. I'm assuming this is because either recentImageList or interestingImageList is now null depending on the activity, therefore can't calculate its size. How would I fix this?

Comment: if(whichActivity ==0)
return recentImageList.size();
else
return interestingImageList.size();

Answer (score 0):

For two different RecyclerView you will need two instance of the adapter. To go to the details activity, it will be better to get the selected or clicked item position in activity and start the details activity from present activity. To get the selected position from the adapter you can use interface. Here is an open source [RecyclerView-Listener](https://github.com/shuza/RecyclerView-Listener) library to get the selected item position. You can use it or understand the concept and implement yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your help! I've fixed it!

I realised that my original code was correct, however the line in my Details Activity: 
    photo = NetworkMgr.getInstance(this).recentImageList.get(photoPosition);
was the problem, as this line retrieved only the position for the recent images and didn't account for the interesting images. Therefore, in my OnClickListener I used an if statement for the two whichActivitys and putExtra a number to determine which arraylist needs to have its position retrieved in Details activity. See below:

ImageListAdapter -

```
    View.OnClickListener onClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (whichActivity == 0) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, DetailsActivity.class);

                int position = ImageViewHolder.this.getLayoutPosition();

                int imageListCode = 1;
                intent.putExtra("PHOTO_POSITION", position);
                intent.putExtra("IMAGELIST_CODE", imageListCode);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
            else if (whichActivity == 1) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, DetailsActivity.class);

                int position = ImageViewHolder.this.getLayoutPosition();

                int imageListCode = 2;
                intent.putExtra("PHOTO_POSITION", position);
                intent.putExtra("IMAGELIST_CODE", imageListCode);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
    }
    };
```

DetailsActivity -

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
photoPosition = intent.getIntExtra("PHOTO_POSITION", 0);
code = intent.getIntExtra("IMAGELIST_CODE", 0);

    if (code == 1) {
        photo = NetworkMgr.getInstance(this).recentImageList.get(photoPosition);
    }
    else if (code == 2) {
        photo = NetworkMgr.getInstance(this).interestingImageList.get(photoPosition);
    }
```